# Thingsboard custom rule nodes - Defined configuration directive 'myTestNodeConfig' is not available

Tags: thingsboard

I created custom RuleNode following https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/rule-node-development/ 
When I deploy and run, and when I insert my Custom Rule node it says

**Defined configuration directive 'myTestNodeConfig' is not available.**

In rule-node-examples project have it defined like this

```
@RuleNode(
        type = ComponentType.FILTER,
        name = "MyTestNode",
        relationTypes = {"True", "False"},
        configClazz = MyTestNodeConfiguration.class,
        nodeDescription = "Checks the existence of the selected key in the message payload.",
        nodeDetails = "If the selected key  exists - send Message via <b>True</b> chain, otherwise <b>False</b> chain is used.",
        uiResources = {"static/rulenode/custom-nodes-config.js"},
        configDirective = "myTestNodeConfig")
public class MyTestNode implements TbNode {
```

In rule-node-examples-ui project have it defined like below

```
import CheckKeyConfigDirective from './check-key-config.directive';
export default angular.module('thingsboard.ruleChain.config.filter', [])
.directive('myTestNodeConfig', CheckKeyConfigDirective)
    .name;
```

Can someone help to figure out whats is missing. Thanks